# SCP QGIS Sentinel 2 plugin authorisation error

Tags: qgis, sentinel-2

I receive an http 401 auth failed error when trying to download Sentinel 2 images using the SCP plugin in QGIS. I registered a new account and confirmed my email but there is no support for new accounts after 21/12/2015. It seems to be possible to use a guest account but how does this work? . I tried this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVS2Ls2bUbk)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use guest / guest as login account and password. the ESA datahub API is still in beta and the login credentials are guest / guest, even though you can create your own account.